# Setting global variables in an ipython shell with functions defined in a script

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, global

I'm having problems with global variables in the ipython shell
I know global variables are bad ect ect but its convenient for this use case,
and anyway the problem is interesting.
The simplified version of the bug is such:
Defined in a script

```py
Five = 0
def set_five(n=5):
    global Five
    Five = n
    return Five
print(Five)
print(set_five())
print(Five)
```

And the output of running that script in the ipython shell is as expected

```py
0
5
5
```

However, If I then try and set the global variable in the shell its fails

```py
> Five
5
> set_five(10)
10
> Five
5
```

more puzzling is that problem does not happen in the python interpreters interactive mode,

This is the ipython start up message

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 24 2021, 12:50:35) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Any help would be much appreciated

thank you

**Solved**
As pointed out below, the issue is that global refers to the module wide name space, and ipython runs in its own module name space.
So if i import the script and then get at its variables via dot notation then it does what its supposed to

```
In [63]: import main

In [64]: main.Five
Out[64]: 5

In [65]: main.set_five(10)
Out[65]: 10

In [66]: main.Five
Out[66]: 10
```

Thank you for this!
Additionally if anyone knows how to some how merge a script into the ipython name space so that the execution behavior is closer to that of the pure python interactive mode, that would be appreciated.

Comment: The ``global`` namespace is *per-module*. The REPL/ipython is a different module (``__main__``) than the one defining ``Five``.

Comment: oh I see, that makes sense